# JS & CSS: Font-color and thickness of a single word in the same sentence line

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following problem:

I want to change the color and thickness of a single word (->(Admin)) in the same sentence line. My code does do what it should, but unfortunately it is totally unformated now and does have line skips. I used JavaScript and CSS, but I am a totally beginner in this field. Probably there is much redundancy in the code.

I used "span", h1 -> child (1)/(2) and so on in the .js file and corresponding entries in the .css file:

.js Datei:

```
<div id="user-info">
      <div><h1><span>{this.props.dataHandler["userData"]["firstname"]} {this.props.dataHandler["userData"]["lastname"]}</span><span> (Admin)</span></h1></div>
      <div><h2><span>Mitarbeiternummer: {this.props.dataHandler["userData"]["userID"]}</span></h2></div>
      <div><a href="/#"onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}><u>Logout</u></a></div>
      </div>
```

.css Datei:

```
#user-info {
    color: white;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0.3vh 0 0 0;
  }

#user-info h1 :nth-child(1) {
    color: white; 
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0; 
     
  }
    
#user-info h1 :nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0.3vh 0 0 0; 
  }

#user-info h2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0.3vh 0 0 0; 
  }

#user-info div{
    font-size: 1.5vh;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because all of your elements are set to just 15% of width.

You can see how narrow `#user-info` is.

[image]

So, your solution is to remove `width: 15%` from `#user-info`.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
#user-info {
    color: white;
    margin: 0.3vh 0 0 0;
  }

#user-info h1 :nth-child(1) {
    color: white; 
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0; 
     
  }
    
#user-info h1 :nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0.3vh 0 0 0; 
  }

#user-info h2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0.3vh 0 0 0; 
  }

#user-info div{
    font-size: 1.5vh;
  }
```

```html
<div id="user-info">
      <div><h1><span>{this.props.dataHandler["userData"]["firstname"]} {this.props.dataHandler["userData"]["lastname"]}</span><span> (Admin)</span></h1></div>
      <div><h2><span>Mitarbeiternummer: {this.props.dataHandler["userData"]["userID"]}</span></h2></div>
      <div><a href="/#"onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}><u>Logout</u></a></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important rule is always to keep it simple, I think this should help you:

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}

h1 {
  color: orange;
}

h1 span {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: red;
}

h2 span {
  color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-info" class="user-info">
  <h1>{this.props.dataHandler["userData"]["firstname"]} {this.props.dataHandler["userData"]["lastname"]}<span> (Admin)</span></h1>
  <h2>Mitarbeiternummer: <span>{this.props.dataHandler["userData"]["userID"]}</span></h2>
  <a href="/#" onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>Logout</a>
</div>
```